# Error in initializing a tf.variable when trying to define the NN as a class

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to define a simple tensorflow graph using a python class as following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class NNclass:

def __init__(self, state_d, action_d, state):
    self.s_dim = state_d
    self.a_dim = action_d
    self.state = state
    self.prediction

@property
def prediction(self):
    a = tf.constant(5, dtype=tf.float32)
    w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(0, 1))
    return tf.add(a, w1)

state = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[None, 1])
NN_instance = NNclass(1, 2, state)

ses = tf.Session()
ses.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

nn_input = np.array([[0.5], [0.7]])
print(ses.run(NN_instance.prediction,  feed_dict={state: nn_input}))
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
```

The way I see it, I'm having an instance of **NNclass** and I go over the tf graph because the **def__init__** goes over prediction method.
But I don't understand why running this yields the above error.
Any help please
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the best practice to pass the result of a function to `sess.run()` as you are doing, and this is causing confusion.

A better practice for configuring your network would be to create a `build_graph()` function where all the tensorflow operations are defined. Then return the tensors you will need to compute (better yet, store them in a dictionary or save them as properties of the object).

Example:

```
def build_graph():
  a = tf.constant(5, dtype=tf.float32)
  w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(0, 1))
  a_plus_w = tf.add(a, w1)
  state = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[None, 1])
  return a_plus_w, state

a_plus_w, state = build_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

nn_input = np.array([[0.5], [0.7]])
print(sess.run(a_plus_w,  feed_dict={state: nn_input}))
```

The key error you're making is that you aren't separating the two phases of development in tensorflow. You have a **"build graph"** phase where you **define** all the math operations you want to perform, then second you have an **"execution"** phase where you use `sess.run` to ask tensorflow to perform computations for you. When you call `sess.run` you need to pass tensorflow the tensor (a tf object that has already been defined in the graph) you want to have computed. You shouldn't be passing tensorflow a function to execute.

Answer (score 4):

`tf.global_variables_initializer()` should be called after all variables is created. In your example, `prediction` function defines `w1` variable which is not initialized until `ses.run()`.

You may create variables inside `__init__` function like below:

```
class NNclass:
    def __init__(self, state_d, action_d, state):
        self.s_dim = state_d
        self.a_dim = action_d
        self.state = state
        self.a = tf.constant(5, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(0, 1))

    @property
    def prediction(self):
        return tf.add(self.a, self.w1)
```

Comment: When I create the instance 'NN_instance' which contains in its init the method 'self.prediction' doesn't that mean that the variables have been created? when I debug I do see the code runs over 'def prediction(self)' method before the ses.run and the global_variables_initializer